# how to detect multiple language in text recognition using firebase MLkit?

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(imageBitmap);

```
    FirebaseVisionCloudTextRecognizerOptions options = new FirebaseVisionCloudTextRecognizerOptions.Builder()
            .setLanguageHints(Arrays.asList("en", "hi"))
            .build();

    FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();
    detector.processImage(firebaseVisionImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {

            displayTextFromImage(firebaseVisionText);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error--" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```